# Some details on ARM Linux boot

Tags: linux, arm, boot, initrd, rootfs

I'm trying to understand the details of linux booting on arm architecture. I did lot of search on the internet and understood so far some details although I feel each time I read an article it brings lot of other new terms and this makes things more complex. I do have 2 boards running linux, an olimex 9261 and a beaglebone black. My expertise in embedded systems especially arm is pretty good, but didn't play too much with linux though (except some user space programs and char drivers in kernel).

Here are my questions:

One one board I have the following uboot output (linux 2.6.30):

```
 bootargs=mem=64M console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/mtdblock1 rw rootfstype=jffs2
 bootcmd= cp.b 0xC0042000 0x22000000 0x00199954; bootm 0x22000000
```

The board has 64MB RAM (mapped at 0x20000000), 512MB nand flash(didn't find mapping so far) and 2MB data flash (mapped at 0xc0000000).

What I don't understand here:

- why there is a mem=64 in the bootargs? Isn't this supposed to be given as ATAG or DTB ?
- why is there a console given as argument when we pass the control to kernel? Is the kernel using the tty already configured by uboot?
- initrd vs rootfs. This is still not clear to me. I know initrd can be included in kernel as a block device or a separate image for which uboot has to pass address details to kernel (true?). Can we have a kernel without an initrd included + another file system, like this jffs2, from which the kernel will run rest of drivers? Actually I'm not able to understand full details of the file system used by kernel at boot. In this setup I have, there are 4 files: uImage, bootstrap, env.bin and jffs2 file system. So there is no initrd. How is this working? And how is the process of rooting the file system pointed in the above bootargs? In my understanding, the kernel should access first the jffs2 file system, then grab the image found in /dev/mtdblock1 and mount it. Perhaps my understanding is wrong. Actually this interaction between kernel and file system is what I seem not to understand.
  In the above bootcmd, the kernel is copied from nand to sdram then bootm jumps to it. But how does the kernel find the jffs at booting time?
  I see this output line during boot:
  VFS: Mounted root (jffs2 filesystem) on device 31:1.

In the board user guide I found this:

WARNING: Due to AT91SAM9261 chip errata booting from NAND flash is
not supported.

...

512MB NAND Flash (seen in Linux as silicon drive).

- After compiling the kernel, I observed the System.map doesn't have all symbols. I checked the vmlinux and it's the same. Does anyone know why? Maybe the compiler was not configured properly?

Many thanks,
Daniel.

Comment: Your question is hard to answer, because it has a dozen sub-questions. Maybe try splitting into multiple questions or rearranging this one, so separate questions can be addressed.

Answer (score 2):

- mem=64 - I **assume** this might be needed before device tree can be loaded. Maybe not.
- tty - but how could the kernel know which tty was configured by bootloader? There has to be some configuration, either passed to, compiled in, or just a default setting.
- initrd (or initramfs) vs. nothing - initrd is just a very small userspace that can ie. prompt for decryption password, wait for USB device with rootfs to be plugged in, or something else. Things could work without, just be sure to then compile in all the necessary modules to boot from rootfs. If I recall correctly, a few years ago initramfs was introduced as initrd replacement. It is a CPIO archive packed inside the kernel and it might be what you're seeing when there's "no initrd"

Comment: I read about CPIO included in all 2.6.30 kernels. In linux doc says, there is no need to mount it as a block device, just create a folder and extract the image there. So we are actually already running a file system before having the initrd mounted? I don't really understand this order of file systems seen and mounted by kernel and the fact that one is mounted as ramdisk. How about the other one, like my jffs2? How is this one "mounted" ?  I think this whole theory of file systems linked to kernel is blurry. And I have read already a lot, but something doesn't match my understanding :(

Answer (score 2):

Most of your questions can be answered by [reading the Documentation](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation) that comes with your Linux source.  Some key files are,

- kernel-parameters.txt
- arm/booting.txt

Please take a look through them as they will have information current to your version of Linux.

---

> One one board I have the following uboot output (linux 2.6.30):

The 2.6.30 kernel pre-dates device trees for the ARM.

> why there is a mem=64 in the bootargs? Isn't this supposed to be given as ATAG or DTB ?

There are two mechanisms.  The **ATAGS** is more flexible as it can specify several non-contiguous banks of memory.  The idea is that boot code can probe the memory and provide it via **ATAGS**.  That is the theory.  It is often tough to do, so allowing a user to specify **mem=64** is a lot easier to implement.  If there are two board types, one with 64MB and one with 128MB, it is up to the user to provide a command line to use the extra memory.

> why is there a console given as argument when we pass the control to kernel? Is the kernel using the tty already configured by uboot?

Some devices have multiple serial ports.  Some kernels may wish to use the 'u-boot' port for something else.  HDSPA modem, printer, etc.  The Linux kernel and the u-boot consoles may be different.  That is a feature.  I often use */dev/null* as the console.  Hardware is often stingy to give an extra serial port.  Maybe you are lucky and your hardware people don't think software is free.

> initrd vs rootfs.

You may boot directly to a file system (rootfs), but all of the code and mechanisms for finding the code must be inside the Linux image.  Even if they are (JFFS2/NAND), you may end up with a corrupt *rootfs* as NAND wears.  The first 128MB of NAND is usually a higher quality.  You may put a Linux with initrd here that is capable of repair of the main file system.  For other boot devices, it may not be straight forward to boot the device and complex decisions can be made in an initrd image.  Often the *initrd* take far less time to *mount* and you may perform some actions more quickly. Finally, you may load different modules and then lock module loading in the initrd.

You may use the *rootfs* directly.  It is simpler to implement.  The *initrd* is much more flexible and powerful.  You may wish to transition from JFFS2 to Ubi/UbiFS.  If you don't have an *initrd*, then this is pretty much impossible (at least much more difficult to implement).

> In this setup I have, there are 4 files: uImage, bootstrap, env.bin and jffs2 file system. So there is no initrd.

The *uImage* may have an *initrd* attached to it.  It is mounted as a ramdisk and after it *unmounts* (and [`switch_root`](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman8/switch_root.8.html) to the new/final *rootfs*) the memory is free to use.  However, your command line has no *initrd* info, so you probably don't have one.

> In my understanding, the kernel should access first the jffs2 file system, then grab the image found in /dev/mtdblock1 and mount it. Perhaps my understanding is wrong. Actually this interaction between kernel and file system is what I seem not to understand. In the above bootcmd, the kernel is copied from nand to sdram then bootm jumps to it. But how does the kernel find the jffs at booting time? I see this output line during boot: VFS: Mounted root (jffs2 filesystem) on device 31:1.

You have information to find the device; `root=/dev/mtdblock1` and you told it the file system type; `rootfstype=jffs2`.  The missing piece is the `init=/sbin/init`.  You can read about it in the [kernel-parameters.txt](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt) for your Linux.  After the JFFS2 is mounted, the *init* code looks for a process to run.  It is the parent process of everything and it will start to execute many different processes.  Typically it is [init](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?init%208), but you can specify `init=/bin/sh` and you will just have a shell to start with.  This can be a good way to develop an *initrd* image as you can test scripts with only one process running.

> After compiling the kernel, I observed the System.map doesn't have all symbols. I checked the vmlinux and it's the same. Does anyone know why? Maybe the compiler was not configured properly?

The *System.map* is really only external functions and data.  It does not include every function.  In fact some functions may not exist due to in-lining.

> WARNING: Due to AT91SAM9261 chip errata booting from NAND flash is not supported.

I guess it is u-boot's job to handle this.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the answers. 
Regarding system.map, that's odd. If I want to debug it based on symbols what shall I do then?
Regarding the initrd, according to my understanding, 
if the ramdisk is attached to kernel at compilation time, then there is no need to pass any address from bootloader. 
As I read the INITRD_PHYS is set to that address. True? In my 2.6.30 kernel I have it defined.
Alternative is to copy a separate initrd image in memory and give address to kernel using ATAGS.

Comment: 2nd comment as I don't have space for all my questions:
For initrd/rootfs: what is the "1st" file system which runs on kernel?
Shall we have all the time a rootfs? If yes, this should point either to initrd or to another
file system like the jffs2 in my case? 
"root=/dev/mtdblock1" => this is a block device, how does it link to my jffs2? How does the kernel find it?
/dev/something means a path on a file system. If there is no file system mounted how does this path make sense
for kernel?2nd comment as I don't have space for all my questions.

Comment: Well, that's the point. I already read lot of docs, something is not matching my understanding, maybe I start with a wrong expectation, don't know. For this reason I posted my questions here. Tutorials I found, but it just seems that they already assume things which I don't know, therefore they are meaningless to me. However, when someone is already experienced in one area doesn't fully understands (perhaps) what I newbie doesn't understand. Thanks for your answers anyway.

Comment: Linux is highly flexible.  There are often twenty different ways to do things.  Do not think there is only one way.  You can have an attached or detached *initrd* or no *initrd* at all.  Some of your questions don't make sense; they might have multiple meanings and I can choose the answer to the wrong question.